# Whats going on in this function?

Tags: function, go

I am failing to understand whats happening with Equal (u T) bool.  Is it a method within a function?    Also what is the difference of a method and a function.  I understand that this function is taking in t of type T and return true or false if t=u.

```
 type T int 
 func (t T) Equal (u T) bool {return t==u}
```

Comment: Please take the [go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1).

Comment: Just wanna say, I've never used Golang but this feature looks pretty cool

Comment: `Equal` is a method on `T`. Please take the tour (the whole thing), but specifically https://tour.golang.org/methods/1

Comment: your question is too wide. For your question on methods see method with receiver https://tour.golang.org/methods/3

Answer (score 2):

That's a [method declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations), and since methods in Go are just functions with a *receiver* they are declared using the keyword `func`.

```
func (t T) Equal (u T) bool {return t==u}
1     2 3  4      5 6  7     8
```

1. the keyword used to declare functions and methods.
2. the method receiver's identifier, using this you can access the receiver inside the body of the method.
3. the method receiver's type.
4. the name of the method.
5. the name of the method's argument, using this you can access the argument inside the body of the method.
6. the type of the method's argument.
7. the return type of the method argument.
8. the body of the method.

---

For comparison, a function that does the same thing would be declared as such:

```
func Equal (t T, u T) bool {return t==u}
```

(no reciever, but takes two arguments)

Comment: Is the purpose of the receiver to allow a method to take on multiple variables of the same type? I see so it reduces typing.  We can now input just a 'receiver'  rather than inputting many arguments.

Comment: @heretolearn No, its purpose is not to allow a method to take on multiple variable of the same type. Why having methods to a type is a very wide and interesting question. However, it requires you to understand what methods and receiver is. Really, please take the go tour or other turtorials towards programing and go.

Comment: No, the purpose of the receiver is that you can define a set of methods on a particular type with which then, among other things, you can implement interfaces.

Comment: So the purpose of the receiver is to restrict methods from only taking on a particular type

Comment: No, the purpose of the receiver is to restrict what type the methods is of. In this example, the `Equal` is `T`'s method and other type, let's say `float64`, can't use it.

Comment: @heretolearn No, I don't think that that's what I said.